# Are the Interrupt Stack and the Kernel Stack the same stack?

Tags: unix, stack, kernel, interrupt

Or the Interrupt Stack is a special stack cointained in Kernel Stack?
I'm a little bit confused because sometimes my book refers at it with only "stack".

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/kernel-stacks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on  kernel configuration (CONFIG_4KSTACKS)

**Case 1**:  When CONFIG_4KSTACKS is not set
         In this case, kernel stack size per thread is 8K( 2 pages) and ISR will use same kernel stack.

**Case 2:**  When CONFIG_4KSTACKS is set.
         In this case, kernel stack size per thread is 4K( 1 page) and ISR will have separate stack of 4k(1 page)

Check http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch06lev1sec5 for more updates.